# How can I set column header text?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I would like to set the text of the columns.  What is the correct syntax for the `GridView`?

```
Me.gvRefBetweenLineOfBiz.DataSource = query
Me.gvRefBetweenLineOfBiz.DataBind()
EnableControlVisibility(True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll likely want to disable the automatic generation of your columns, and create a  [BoundField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.aspx) for each column you want displayed in your GridView.  Each `BoundField` has a `HeaderText` property which controls the column's header text.

From the docs:

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
    datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
    autogeneratecolumns="false"
    autogenerateeditbutton="true"
    allowpaging="true" 
    datakeynames="CustomerID"  
    runat="server">

    <columns>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="CustomerID"
        readonly="true"      
        headertext="Customer ID"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="CompanyName"
        convertemptystringtonull="true"
        headertext="Customer Name"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="Address"
        convertemptystringtonull="true"
        headertext="Address"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="City"
        convertemptystringtonull="true"
        headertext="City"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="PostalCode"
        convertemptystringtonull="true"
        headertext="ZIP Code"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="Country"
        convertemptystringtonull="true"
        headertext="Country"/>
    </columns>

  </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: datakeynames="CustomerID" ==> I'm getting an error, it says the report does not contain a property with the name 'CustomerID'.  Where does that name derive .. I thought you just created a name; does it relate to something else?

Comment: `datakeynames` represents the PK of your datasource.  Older version of asp.net had programmers putting PK identifiers into boundifleds, and setting visible = false.  That's not secure.  So a later version of asp.net added the datakeynames property, which is where you store a row's PK.  You access the actual values with: `yourGridView.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values["yourKeyName"]`

Comment: See also:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx